# Automatically Running Perl Script

Tags: perl, automation

Is it possible to have a Perl Program constantly running while my PC is on?

If so, how do you do it?

Comment: Make it a service or daemon. But the answer will depend on what operating system you are running. Can we assume that pc means windows?

Comment: @Doon: I am running Windows (Windows 7). And what do you mean service or daemon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options. You can run it as a service as Doon suggested above. If you just want it to run in the background. It sounds like you are running a script from the command line and want to close the prompt/shell, but have it keep running.

Linux: http://www.washington.edu/computing/unix/background.html

I see your follow up that you are on windows, so this existing question may help you out: https://serverfault.com/questions/9038/run-a-bat-file-in-a-scheduled-task-without-a-window

To answer your follow up, a service/daemon is a background process that is always running such as "svchost.exe". If you are on windows, go go run and type "services.msc" - this will bring up the service manager. There are ways to create and manage services from arbitrary programs, but that sounds like its beyond your needs right now.

Answer (score 2):

If executing upon login is ok and if Windows is configured to recognize and execute Perl scripts you can try adding (a shortcut to) the script to the `Startup` folder.